# C# Qyoto bindings for webkit on WinCE platform

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, qtwebkit

is it possible to use [QTWebKit](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtwebkit.html) on WinCE (5.0, 6.0) using .NET Compact Framework (2.0 and higher)? If yes, any idea where to start from(are compiled binaries available somewhere)?
I was reading about [Qyoto project](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Qyoto) as an optimal solution but there are no references on WinCE platform.
Best regards,
Frenk

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out WebKit.NET?  I know they currently target .Net 2.0 using WinCairo, but I don't think many of the calls they are making are outside the scope of the Compact Framework, and the Compact Framework does support Interop, so it should work in theory...